# PHP move_upload_file() not working on godaddy server

Tags: php

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];

$move = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");

    if ($move != true) {
        echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";

        exit();
    }
```

This is my code on my local machine and work perfectly but when I upload to my server online I got an error "500 - Internal server error."

Comment: how about adding an absolute path to your uploads folder?  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/$filename"` ?

Comment: let me try this @roullie..thanks :)

Comment: I got the same error @roullie.

Comment: Check if there is write permission for uploads folder in server

Comment: You should check your error log

Comment: I already set the permission to 0777 and check if  the folder is writable but I still got this error.

@madforstrength how to show the detail error in godaddy?

Comment: "Response: 500 'SITE': command not understood"

I got this from filezilla setting permission to uploads folder..